What is the white slit on the edge of my Apple Magic Keyboard?
I can't find any information on what this slit is. Is it supposed to light up or is it the bluetooth interface?

The model is a1644 2020/09

Like most Apple devices that have some sort of break in the metal bezel, that is an antenna. This one is for Bluetooth.
